# I want to convert api json data to value c#

Tags: c#, json, api

Hi i'm newbie in c# dev and i'm not good at english i try to get value from json but it gives error [https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/articles/convert-json-string-to-object-in-csharp]

If anyone can help me with simple code I would be very grateful.

```
{
    "result": [{
        "company": "Server",
        "results": [{
            "name": "Server-01",
            "access": ["8.8.8.8:443", "1.1.1.1:443"],
            "is_ok": "0"
        }, {
            "name": "Server-02",
            "access": ["8.8.8.8:443", "1.1.1.1:443"],
            "is_ok": "0"
        }, {
            "name": "Server-03",
            "access": ["8.8.8.8:443", "1.1.1.1:443"],
            "is_ok": "1"
        }, {
            "name": "Server-04",
            "access": ["8.8.8.8:443", "1.1.1.1:443"],
            "is_ok": "0"
        }, {
            "name": "Server-05",
            "access": ["8.8.8.8:443", "1.1.1.1:443"],
            "is_ok": "0"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: "i try to get value from json" I see no code?

Comment: you gave us the json data. show the code, and details about the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# can be different. Like [.Net Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/) or [.Net Core / .Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/), so next time please provide which framework do you use.

The are two common ways to deserialize JSON string - [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) (3rd party) or [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=net-6.0) (part of .Net).

For correct deserealization first of all you must provide valid models. But sometimes JSON properties violates [C# Naming Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions) or they even can't be represented in code (e.g. property name with whitespace or "is_ok" from your JSON). To avoid this you must to use [property attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/) that connect your property in code and property in JSON. It's:

- `[JsonProperty("PropertyName")]` for Json.NET
- `[JsonPropertyName("PropertyName")]` for System.Text.Json

So, summing up the above, you must add models similar to this:

```
public class ResultWrapper
{
    [JsonProperty("result")] //use one of it based on selected library
    [JsonPropertyName("result")]
    public List<Result> Result { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    [JsonProperty("company")]
    [JsonPropertyName("company")]
    public string Company { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("results")]
    [JsonPropertyName("results")]
    public List<ResultItem> Results { get; set; }
}

public class ResultItem
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("access")]
    [JsonPropertyName("access")]
    public List<string> Access { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("is_ok")]
    [JsonPropertyName("is_ok")]
    public string IsOk { get; set; }
}
```

and use one of next deserealization methods:

```
//Json.Net
var deserializedJsonNet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultWrapper>(jsonFromQuestion);
//System.Text.Json
var deserializedSystemTextJson = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResultWrapper>(jsonFromQuestion);
```